# DLL fails to load if unused ref class is removed

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, uwp, windows-runtime

I'm running into a very strange problem trying to compile and use a windows runtime component within an UWP application (VS2017 community 15.9.13 with NetCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform 6.2.8, compiled without /clr but with /ZW).

It is basically something like the [Grayscaletransform](https://github.com/r2d2rigo/UWP-Samples/blob/master/CustomVideoEffect/CustomVideoEffect.VideoEffects/GrayscaleVideoEffect.cs). The runtime component is actually working as expected, now I wanted to remove some unused code. However, as soon as I remove it from a particular file and recompile, it indeed compiles, links, but the DLL does not load any more.

Here's some example code that I have to put in:

```
ref class DummyU sealed
{
public:
    DummyU() {}
};

DummyU^ CreateDummyU()
{
    return ref new DummyU();
}
```

The code just makes it work, although it is a) not referenced at all and b) does not do anything useful.

The result of removing it:

```
Exception thrown at 0x0EFF322F (vccorlib140d_app.dll) in TestAppUWP.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
```

in

```
STDAPI DllGetActivationFactory(_In_ HSTRING activatibleClassId, _Deref_out_ IActivationFactory** ppFactory)
{
    return Platform::Details::GetActivationFactory(Microsoft::WRL::Details::ModuleBase::module_, activatibleClassId, ppFactory);
}
```

function in `dllexports.cpp` which is part of VS. The `module_` becomes `NULL`.

Does anyone have an idea if there are any known bugs with respect to the windows runtime not being initialized/used properly if there is no explicit instantiation of a ref class in a file?

**EDIT 1:**

Here's the [link](https://github.com/belveder79/mediacapture) to the full source code:

Comment: That code is not C++.

Comment: it is rather some mixture of Visual-C++ and C++ and .NET actually...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening here is that you're mixing modes a bit. Since you've compiled your C++ code with the /CX flag, you've told the compiler to enable winrt extensions to produce a WinRT DLL. In practice though, none of your code is actually using the CX extensions to implement classes. You're using WRL and standards C++. The compiler looks at the DLL, finds no CX-style WinRT classes, and doesn't set up the module, accordingly.

This is basically an untested & unsupported case, since you've chosen to say that you want to expose ref classes by picking a UWP component library project type, but then didn't actually provide any ref classes. It happens that under the hood, /CX effectively uses WRL, so you can nudge it along and initialize the state to work correctly, but you're kinda hacking the implementation details of the system.

There are two options I would recommend, either works: just make the project a non-CX Win32 DLL and init the module as described above. Or, better yet, flip over to [C++ /WinRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/), which will give you better support for the WinRT types than /CX and allow you to more easily mix in the classic COM types in your implementation. You can get started by just turning off the /CX flag in the compiler switches, then start updating the code accordingly.

Ben

Comment: ok, I got your point about switching to C++/WinRT, but I think the point about exposing is not entirely true actually, and that puzzles me. First, this is mainly Microsoft sample code, so I would expect that at least they know what they are doing. I did not invent that myself - the MediaFoundation is a nightmare anyway. And second, I am indeed having quite a few ref classes in the codebase which are simply necessary to get the module to play with C#/.NET. It's just this single *Stream* file that probably does not have a ref class, but at least to me that should not break it.

Comment: I should clarify. I browsed through the project you shared. Specifically in the project you shared in the comment to the other answer (https://github.com/belveder79/mediacapture), there are no ref classes in the VizarioSource DLL project from what I can see. All of the objects in that project are classic COM objects. A single compilation unit not having a ref class should not be an issue, as long as the linked module has at least one. If you're still seeing the issue and can share source, I'd be happy to look again and see if I can help further.

Comment: @BenKuhn Probably this version: https://github.com/belveder79/mediacapture/commit/ca1f0ce651a9505ad3afa85f3f63bf0cdcf62d92

Answer (score 1):

You might have wrong .winmd file for your component. WinRT components made in C++ produce two outputs, dll and winmd. Both must match. It's possible you have them from different builds.

Another possible reason is error in manifest. The manifest of the app [must include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/uapmanifestschema/generate-package-manifest#windows-runtime-registration-extensions) all referenced runtime components.

BTW, for native DLLs written in classic C++ and exposing C API, deployment is simpler, you include a DLL in the package and they just work, with `[DllImport]` if you're consuming them from C#.

**Update:** You can replace that `ref class` with the following code, works on my PC.

```
struct ModuleStaticInitialize
{
    ModuleStaticInitialize()
    {
        Microsoft::WRL::Module<Microsoft::WRL::InProc>::GetModule();
    }
};
static ModuleStaticInitialize s_moduleInit;
```

Probably a bug in Microsoft's runtime somewhere.

Comment: those are all valid points, but it most be something different. Here is the [link](https://github.com/belveder79/mediacapture) to the full source. Just clone, restore nuget packages and compile. It should work, but once you remove lines 113ff in VizarioMediaStream.cpp, it breaks...

Comment: you are completely right - this works, so it seems that explicit initialization works... really seems to be a bug somewhere... thanks a lot!